# Почему домашний дух - домовОй, книга и церковь - домОвые, а день - дУхов?

Tags: грамматика

В относительных прилагательных с суффиксами ОВ и Н  **ударение может падать на корневой гласный, суффикс или окончание.** Иногда влияние оказывает фонетика, но часто мы можем сделать ударным любой слог.

Обычно встречаются парные варианты: ***перенОсный и переноснОй, перехОдный и переходнОй, харАктерный и характЕрный, устАвный и уставнОй, вАловый и валовОй, Оптовый и оптОвый.***

Особенно интересен перенос ударения на окончание (минуя суффикс), что он означает? Различия могут относиться к стилю или смыслу, но и стиль часто связан с точностью смысла по принципу "неточный смысл ― разговорный стиль".

Или вот  интересный вариант: **грунт ― грунтОвый, грунтовОй.** Можно ударение поставить на любом слоге, но нормируются два варианта. А У Резниченко (2010 год) ― только **грунтовОй**, грунтОвый ― неправ.! Почему так?

**И вопросы:**

1) Можно ли в этих парных вариантах **сделать правильный выбор без словаря**, ориентируясь на  семантику словосочетания?

2) **Почему все-таки**  (1) домашний дух ― это  домовОй, а не домОвый и (2) почему  верно "дух ― дУхов, но не "дух ― дУховый/духОвый/духовОй"?

Answer (score 1):

> (2) почему верно "дух ― дУхов, но не "дух ― дУховый/духОвый/духовОй"?

Я испытываю некоторый страх, сталкиваясь с вопросами, начинающимися с"почему". Ну язык так устроен, нет здесь однозначной причинно-следственной связи. 
Все притяжательные прилагательные (в исходном смысле, то есть образованные от грамматически одушевленных существительных) тяготеют к кратким формам. Это "закон", правда, никогда не был императивен, а с постепенным исчезновением кратких форм также постепенно вообще утрачивает силу, но исторические формы пока еще держатся. Отец - отцов, солдат - солдатов. И параллельно для существительных на -а/-я: дядя - дядин, мама-мамин. (Ну и альтернативная форма - на ий/ья - лисий, рыбий, собачья, но это отдельный разговор). В силу чувства грамматической ненормативности полные прилагательные такого типа используются крайне редко, вместо них довольно продуктивной является форма на -(ов/ин/-)ский: отцовский, воровской, цыганский - но она не далеко не для всех прилагательных нормативна, хотя постепенно расширяет сферу применимости.

Так что выбор краткой формы для "духов" не должен вызывать каких-то сомнений. Тут вопрос-то в другом. Можно ли образовать полную форму для вновь возникшего значения. И если да, то какую - духовый или духовской.

> (1) домашний дух ― это домовОй, а не домОвый

Если сочтете за объяснение, то домовой - он как водяной, а домовый - это было бы как "водный". Отчасти сюда идет и пара "леший" - "лесной": первое слово єтой пары по другой модели сделано, но стремление разделить значения налицо.

> Или вот интересный вариант: грунт ― грунтОвый, грунтовОй... Почему так?

Почему так у Резниченко? Или почему одно неправильно?
Собственно ни то ни другое ответа не имеет, но если вы насчет того, что там Резниченко написал, то это вопрос хотя бы не абсурден сам по себе. Вариант грУнтовый выбивается из общей модели, которая переносит ударение в прилагательном на "-овый", если оно в принципе обладает подвижностью и в словоформе где-то (обычно во множественном или единственном именительного) попадает на последний слог. Винт-винты-винтовой. Вахта-в**а**хты-вахтовый...

Есть масса исключений в обе стороны, но тенденция имеет место.
Поэтому грунт-грунт**ы**-грунтовой следует общей схеме, а грУнтовый совсем уж из неё выбивается, так не говорят в принципе, поэтому Резниченко о нем и не упоминает. А два других варианта распространены, поэтому указание на неправильность одного из них вполне уместно.

Другое дело, что Резниченко, видимо, ошибается. Грунтовый-грунтовой - различаются по значению, а не по нормативности.

> Особенно интересен перенос ударения на окончание (минуя суффикс), что
>   он означает?

С точки зрения семантики - ничего. Разве что ударное окончание как-то может свидетельствовать о большей субстантивации слова (вестовой, ездовой) и о том, что оно пришло из профжаргона, Так, кстати, и было со словом грунт**ы**-грунтов**о**й, где этот вариант из профессиональной речи победил когда-то нормативный гр**у**нты-грунт**о**вый - не во всех, правда, значениях, а только связанных со строительством. У художников гр**у**нты и грунтовый (слой).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, которое я поняла следующим образом. Какие-то семантические различия ударение обозначает, но определить их не представляется возможным. Я это мнение не разделяю и считаю, что закономерность выявить можно и, главное, нужно.  Не такая это глубокая тайна, которая недоступна человеческому мышлению.  Надо сказать, что эта тема не очень популярна у лингвистов, но я видела в Сети некоторые разработки.  К сожалению, у меня нет авторитетных данных  по этому вопросу.

Comment: Примечание. Вот если бы выделить грант в миллион долларов на эту тему, то сразу бы  все закономерности в постановке ударения обозначились бы и всё причудливое прояснилось бы.