# Домовый или домовой храм?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, окончания

Привык к первому варианту, но услышал второй и, загуглив, увидел, что на "домовый" только чуть больше чем в 2 раза больше результатов. У меня "домов**о**й храм" ассоциируется исключительно с персонажем *домовым. :))*

Comment: Гляньте еще здесь. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441648

Comment: *с персонажем домовым.* - так оно и есть в общем-то.

Comment: @behemothus: спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Меня нисколько не удивляет сочетание **«домовОй храм»,** оно мне представляется вполне обоснованным. Но вот объяснить это в двух словах не получится.

Я считаю, что **ударение в русском языке – это вещь в себе,** его природа не кажется доступной даже  для носителей языка. И живет оно особенной жизнью, только внешняя сторона которой фиксируется словарями.

1. Вот я вижу в ответе: «Формы (домовой и домовый) являются альтернативными. Домовый в большинстве случаев считается устаревшим...» Да неужели? **А словари вы пробовали почитать?**

**ДомОвый,** 1. к Дом. Д. водопровод. Д-ые ворота. Д-ая контора (контора домоуправления). Д-ая книга (книга для регистрации жильцов, живущих в доме). 2. Устар. =Домашний (2 зн.). Д. лекарь. Д-ая церковь (принадлежащая одной семье).  3. Составная часть некоторых названий животных, насекомых, обитающих в доме. Д-ая мышь. Д. паук. Д. сверчок.

**ДомовОй**; м. В народных поверьях: добрый или злой дух, живущий в доме.

2. Итак, в современных словарях действительно говорится, что только домашний дух произносится как **домовОй**. В письменных текстах об ударении можно судить только по форме **мужского рода**: домОвый или домовОй. И вот мы видим, что раньше использовалось выражение **«домовОй храм»** и, вероятно, считалось нормированным. Также тексты подтверждают существования таких сочетаний, как  **«домовОй комитет» и «домовОй дух»:**

(1) Трубинов Ю. В. Первый **домовой храм** Петербурга… [Т. А. Базарова. План петровского Петербурга. Источниковедческое исследование (2003)]

(2) И вот **домовой комитет** требует сдачи всего этого в 24 часа, предупреждая, что иначе я буду арестован. [Ф. И. Шаляпин. Моим детям (1932)]

(3) Времена перемалывали хозяев... унижали художественное строение, и все же в нем обитал какой-то многотерпеливый и всезнающий **домовой дух.** [Владимир Рецептер. Узлов, или Обращение к Казанове (1993)]

3. **«ДомовОй комитет** – это вообще отдельная страница в истории России. "Первые домовые комитеты появились ещё в 1917 году, однако их настоящий рассвет можно смело приписывать концу 60-х годов. Именно тогда с подачи властей РСФСР управдом стал другом человека, что и констатировала в знаменитом фильме «Бриллиантовая рука» Леонида Гайдая героиня Нонны Мордюковой».

И это был именно домовОй комитет, что можно видеть **из документов** (постановление Совета Министров РСФСР и ВЦСПС о домовых комитетах от 9 августа 1968 года, отмененное совсем недавно). Там используется термин «домОвый комитет», хотя вот современный писатель Д. Быков иронически пишет о таком ударении:
― Она произносила «домовОй», с ударением на последнем слоге, **словно комитет состоял из мелких домашних божеств…** [Дмитрий Быков. Орфография (2002)]

4. А теперь о самом главном: **почему меняется ударение в этих словах,** можем ли мы судить о правильности произношения, не обращаясь к словарям? Прежде всего, есть ли **семантическая разница** в значении прилагательных «домовый» и «домовой»?
   Я могу рассказать о собственном понимании проблемы, точно так же как вы можете иметь свою точку зрения на это.

Ударение на основе обозначает **тесную связь с существительным «дом»,** отнесенность к дому. Именно это значение закреплено в современных словарях. Смещение ударения на окончание связано **с обобщением значения, с появлением нового качества.** ДомовОй храм – это не только храм, принадлежащий частному владению, вероятно, его внешнее и внутреннее устройство также имеет особые черты. ДомовОй дух (домовОй), домовОй комитет – это особые понятия с вполне конкретным содержанием, а не просто отнесенные к дому.

Поэтому прилагательное «домовОй» **как бы сопротивляется окончательному исключению из языка.** В качестве примера можно привести ненормированное употребление сочетаний **«домовОй паук», «домовОй воробей».** Вероятно, эти птицы и насекомые имеют особые повадки, особенный образ жизни, а не только живут в доме или около домов:

Прямо в мусорные ящики залетают в Киеве зимой голуби, черные дрозды, большие синицы, **домовой воробей**. [Г. А. Мамонов. Экскурсия на помойку // «Биология», 2003.10.08]

Тот поведал, что «**домовой паук** предсказывает наступление морозов». [И. Косиков. Животные на войне // «Техника - молодежи», 1977]

5. **ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, **можно понять заданный вопрос:** "Почему в настоящее время на *домовый* поисковик дает только чуть больше чем в 2 раза больше результатов?"

(1) ДомОвый храм – это **нормированный словарный вариант** со значением «принадлежащий частному дому, одной семье».

(2) ДомовОй храм – ненормированный вариант с **дополнительным**  значением «имеющий определенные  особенности архитектуры и внутренней организации пространства», который также связан с **исторической традицией** употребления.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Посмотрела бумажные орфоэпические словари.

1. У Резнченко (2004 год): домовОй  – дух (сущ.), домОвый (прил.). Приведен пример из стихотворения М. Кузмина (в домОвых церквах), почему-то поставлено ударение.  Во всех остальных словарях после 2004 года – аналогично.
2. А вот у Аванесова (1987 год) приведены две формы без комментариев: домовОй, -Ого и домОвый,-ая, -ое.

Comment: Позвольте добавить к Вашему ответу такой комментарий (просто он недостаточен для отдельного ответа, а информация интересная): А.А. Зализняк писал, что прилагательные "дом**о**вый -- домов**о**й" получили особое ударение по индивидуальным причинам (он не смог подвести под многообразие вариантов единое правило), а другой лингвист К.С. Горбачевич считал, что есть все основания полагать, что в дальнейшем закрепится наконечное ударение.

Comment: Спасибо. Такю интересную и важную в данной теме информацию  хорошо бы оформить как ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon!

Answer (score 1):

Формы являются альтернативными. *Домовый* в большинстве случаев считается устаревшим, но тут как раз тот случай, когда стоит его использовать.

Касательно частотности, куда чаще (по статистике [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams)) в документах употребляется *домовая церковь* нежели *домовой/-ый храм*:

[image: статистика употребления]

Но вы можете найти употребления, например из путеводителя<1> 1833 года публикации:

> Институтъ сей имѣетъ свою особую библiотеку, Минералогическiй и Физическiй кабинеты и свой **домо́вый** храмъ, сооруженный по соизволенiю покойнаго Императора.

---

1. Новый путеводитель по Москвѣ, первопрестольной столицѣ государства россійскаго, Москва, Университетская Типография, 1833

Comment: Диаграмма, безусловно, красивая. Но по ней **никак** невозможно понять: домо́вая церковь или домова́я церковь? А в этом, собственно, и есть **суть** вопроса (ведь в женском и среднем роде *написание* совпадает).

Comment: Никак нет! Домовая церковь, домовая утварь, домовая посуда, домовая лампада, домовая свеча, домовая икона — **где же** (без соответствующего контекста) Вы поставите ударение?

Comment: Вы противоречите **самому себе**: _она показывает, что частота использования домовый выше частоты использования домовой, а значит, демонстрирует, что домова́я будет более популярным вариантом._ Домо́вый — ж. р. домо́вая; домово́й — ж. р. домова́я.

Comment: @JKlen Вы уверены, что правильно поставили ударение в последней цитате? (Это ведь Ваше ударение, а не оригинальное?) В XVIII в. ударение в слове "домовый" падало на последний слог, потом постепенно смещалось на второй, но я не знаю, когда оно окончательно закрепилось на втором слоге. А "Путеводитель ..." был написан ещё в 1826-м.

Comment: Спасибо, извините за небрежность (я смотрел издание 1831 г., в котором не было ударения).

Comment: @JKlen "Формы являются альтернативными. Домовый в большинстве случаев считается устаревшим". Из какого словаря эта информация? Также зачем приведен график на "домовая церковь"? Что он дает?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!